# How to properly call another function while parsing current page?

Tags: python, scrapy

Currently, I am trying to scrape the IMDB movie pages and so far, I am able to scrape the movie details. However, to scrape user reviews, I have to move to a separate page from the movie page itself, which I am currently unsure if my approach to deal with it is correct.

I am using a global variable (data[]) to store the different fields (which will ultimately be dumped into a json file for elasticsearch), however, one of my functions does not seem to be called, and I am not sure what am I missing

The general logic that I am thinking of is as follows:

1. Grab all the links in my list (parse_movie_list)
2. For each Link, go inside and scrape details of that individual movie (parse_individual_movie)
3. Once done, go to scrape the reviews (parse_individual_movie_reviews)
4. Yield data

---

```
def parse_movie_list(self, response):
    links = response.css('span.lister-item-header a::attr(href)').extract()
    for link in links:
        yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_individual_movie)
def parse_individual_movie(self, response):

    reviewlink = response.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'quicklinksMainSection')]/a[3]/@href").extract()[0] or None
    data['reviewlink'] = reviewlink
    newlink = "https://www.imdb.com"+reviewlink
    request = scrapy.Request(newlink,callback=self.parse_individual_movie_reviews)        

    yield data

def parse_individual_movie_reviews(self,response):

    reviews = response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "main")/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/text()').extract() or None

    data['reviewLA'] =  [reviews.strip() for review in reviews] or None

    yield reviews
```

Right now, my problem appears to be that parse_individual_movie_reviews is not called (as the final json does not reflect the existence of reviewLA), ideally the goal is to have reviewLA containing the scraped user reviews from the document.

Comment: Try to use yield from

Comment: can you post full code of yours so we can check and amend it.